# Can I force Tor/Polipo to use locally defined hosts?

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file, tor

I would like to use addresses defined in my hosts file while using Tor. I have the Tor (non-browser) bundle installed: Tor, Polipo and Vidalia. I do not use Torbutton. My browsing is normally done through Firefox with FoxyProxy configured to use Polipo (127.0.0.1:8118), though I occasionally use other applications, sometimes directly through Tor (127.0.0.1:9050).

Specifically, in my Hosts file, I have definitions such as `192.168.1.1 modem` and `192.168.2.1 router`. Those work when using a direct connection, but when I go through Tor on FoxyProxy they never resolve. A workaround with FoxyProxy is to blacklist those particular addresses (`http://modem/*`, `http://router/*`), but this does not solve for other programs and cannot be easily done with the thousands of addresses SpyBot adds to the hosts file.

Is there a way to force Tor to look at the hosts file before passing DNS requests through to the network? Forcing Tor to run all DNS requests locally (i.e. through my hosts file, then my ISP - the Windows defined order) is also acceptable. A fix on Polipo's side of things is useful, but I'd prefer one for Tor.

This question is similar to [Tor config to ignore LAN hosts](https://superuser.com/questions/322274/tor-config-to-ignore-lan-hosts), however not all the addresses in my hosts file are local.